# Problems with file indexing in eclipse make project from CubeMX

Tags: c, makefile, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I had a problem when I imported the generated make project using CubeMX, Eclipse does not index the files from the STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver folder. At the same time, the project is built using make without errors. That it is definitely a problem of file indexing.

[image: Eclipse Index errors]

I found that you can connect the directory through "CDT User Settings Entires". But it didn't help me or I'm doing it wrong. Please do not write about other integrated development environments, I know about them.

I just want to learn how to properly import a make project from CubeMX into Eclipse. If you know the working method, tell me how to do it correctly.

I tried mounting the directory in CDT but it didn't help. The preprocessor and compiler have nothing to do with it, because building the project through make happens correctly. This project does not use the Eclipse build system, so it makes no sense to connect something there, because as I said, this is a purely indexing problem

Comment: You have to add the include paths in the Project Settings to "Paths & Symbols" page on the "Includes" tab. And, you might have to add also specific defines in the "Symbols" tab. Importing a makefile project usually does not add anything to these settings. If you also set a specific compiler, it may detect this at build time, when on the "Preprocessor Include Paths, macros" page on the "Providers" tab you enable e.g. the "CDT (Arm) Cross GCC Compiler settings" and "CDT GCC Build Output Parser".

Comment: i did that but it does nothing. In general, include does not apply if compiled directly by calling the compiler with a makefile, it is not even used: "Paths & Symbols"

Comment: The "Paths & Symbols" is also used in unmanaged Makefile projects by the indexer. But, it depends on the include (e.g. #include "xxx/yyy/test.h" vs #include "test.h" if you just have to add the "Driver" directory or ""Driver/xxx/yyy" to the include paths. That's why I suggested on the "CDT GCC Build Output Parser". If you start a makefile build from within Eclipse, and the compiler output is the real command line and not pretty printed, it could pickup the information from e.g. "gcc **-IDriver/xxx/yyy** -c myfile.c -o myfile.o".